# Repeat N1:Nx rows Y1:Yx times?

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a Google sheet for an address label mail merge to direct people to their nearest outlet.

For 105 people, it might be Store 2 at 300 Block St; for another 60, it might be Store 8 at 55 Front Ave.

The goal is to have Google Sheets output a table with 105 rows of "Store 2; 300 Block Street", 60 rows of "Store 8; 55 Front Ave", etc.

I've tried using

```
transpose(split(rept("<cell with address>"&",", "<number of rows>"), ","))
```

but that's super laborious and error-prone to type out if I have 30 locations to repeat the process for.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I managed to solve the problem soon after posting this but have left it up to see if there was a better way. The key to getting it working was using JOIN. Here is what I ended up using:

```
=arrayformula(transpose(split(join(",",rept(F2:F&",",H2:H)),",")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a master key table which will serve as a feeding ground for this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]

---

or standalone like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 {"300 Block Street"; "55 Front Ave"; "102 King Street"}, ",")&",", 
 {10; 6; 2}))), ","))
```

[image: 0]